# HTML5 <figure> tag having problem with Firefox 5

Tags: css, html, firefox-5, cross-browser

I am a beginner in HTML5, I downloaded a template and started working on it, it worked fine with every other browser (including IE) but the issue is the layout breaks in Firefox 5. Please help.
Thanks. Avirat.

P.S.: U can find my layout at http://www.108medicalid.com

Comment: Please edit your question and describe the problem you are having. Even if I visit the website you linked to I cannot see anything wrong.

Comment: The problem is with Firefox 5, IE 9. Have you tested on it?

Comment: Yes, I did. Please explain the problem instead of expecting us to guess it.

Comment: Actually what happens I've wrapped the images in <figure> and this <figure> along with some text is in <p> and I've applied some padding and margin to <p>. But due to <figure> the margin and padding is not rendered in FF5 and IE9.

Comment: @Wladimir I've also uploaded a error screen shot, you can find it on below link, http://www.108medicalid.com/error.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Did you have that issue in Firefox 4 also?

When Firefox 4 came out I noticed that there was now default styling for `figure` and it caused weird spacing issues. I simply set:

```
margin:0;
```

in my stylesheet for `figure` and all worked the way it was supposed to.

Comment: Thanks for help, but setting margin:0 didn't solved my issue. And no I didn't tried it with FF4.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I've solved the problem. I just removed the <figure> and added <p> to every image. This solved my problem. :)

Comment: Yeah but it didn't really fix it and if you wanted to use HTML5 correctly, <figure> is definitely more apt and it would be good to see what was/is causing the issue. Ah well, whatever works for you I guess!